# why OpenCV only works with terminal and not VSCode?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, visual-studio-code, terminal

so I have s simple python code that opens a webcam using opencv.

it works fine on the terminal but when I try to run it in vscode I get this:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/salahqamachi/Desktop/testing/ss/camera.py", line 2, in
> <module>
>     import cv2 ImportError: No module named cv2
```

I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15, python 3.9 (latest from the official website), and vscode with python extension installed.

I tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling python, vscode and opencv.
- updating python from terminal.
- added "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--generate-members"]" in setting.json in vscode.
- tried using code runner and default vscode's debugging.
- change the python interpreter with command + shift + p

again, the code works correctly in the terminal, but not in vscode.

please comment any suggestions on how I can fix it, thanks.

Comment: check `sys.executable` in both environments. It it the same?

Comment: am getting this when I run it, 
zsh: command not found: sys.executable

Comment: That should be done in python. Create a script  called mytest.py containing `import sys;print(sys.executable)` and run it in both environments. You may have more than one python installed, and vccode may be using one without cv.

Comment: its not even running it on vscode it's saying
final newline missing (pylint)
missing module

Comment: how do I completely uninstall python?
Because you're right I have more than one python installed...
I think uninstalling all of them and reinstalling just the latest one would be better

Comment: try typing 
`which python`
in each shell to see which interpreter is running

Comment: I don't use Mac but you don't want to uninstall whatever is default on your machine.

Comment: The Python env used in VSCode doesn't match your terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use "`pip show opencv-python`" in the VSCode terminal to check where the module "cv" is installed, then click on the Python environment in the lower left corner of VSCode and change it to the environment where the module "cv" is installed.

[image]

Run:

[image]

More reference: [Environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: The OP wants to use the same env between VSCode and the terminal where the terminal already has OpenCV installed.  Installing OpenCV in the different env is not what they want.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are more than one python installation in your machine one must be installed outside the VS code and other one installed in VS code.

And your OpenCV is installion is not mapped with python installation that uses vs code .

You need to configure the pyhon version in the VS code that is mapped with OpenCV.

1. To check all the python installation in your machine using following command in the cmd prompt

`where python`

Then check vs code is mapped with which version of python using below statment in the python file  ​

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If the python path is different than openCV installed then need change by following below image

[image]